Flask redirection if URL matches pattern
How do I tell my flask app to redirect everything that ends .html to non-html counterpart? I mean I want:
http://127.0.0.1:5000/stats.html -> http://127.0.0.1:5000/stats
http://127.0.0.1:5000/SomethingElse.html -> http://127.0.0.1:5000/SomethingElse
Its obvious that request firstly needs to be matched against regualar expression but my question is how do I force my @app.route to do regex verification?

if you would run it on server behind Apache or Nginx then you could configure Apache or Nginx for this.
